# Bigquery SQL Multiple Count group-by in single query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data set where a user can take several actions and each action is timestamped.

| User | Action 1 | Action 2 | Action 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5-2-2022 | null | 4-1-2022 |
| 2 | 4-2-2022 | 4-1-2022 | 4-1-2022 |
| 3 | 1-2-2022 | null | null |

I want to count the actions by date:

| Date | Action 1 | Action 2 | Action 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-2-2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4-1-2022 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 4-2-2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5-2-2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I'm struggling to figure out how to do this in Bigquery SQL and I'm not even sure what words to google. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select * from your_table
  unpivot (date for col in (action1, action2, action3))
)
pivot (count(distinct user) for col in ('action1', 'action2', 'action3'))
```

[image]